Dropdown reload when it is in Radio Ant design
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import type { RadioChangeEvent } from "antd";
import { Input, Radio, Space, Select } from "antd";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1);

  const onChange = (e: RadioChangeEvent) => {
    console.log("radio checked", e.target.value);
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Radio.Group onChange={onChange} value={value}>
      <Space direction="vertical">
        <Radio value={1}>Option A</Radio>
        <Radio value={2}>Option B</Radio>
        <Radio value={3}>Option C</Radio>
        <Radio value={4}>
          <Select
            defaultValue="lucy"
            style={{ width: 120 }}
            options={[
              { value: "jack", label: "Jack" },
              { value: "lucy", label: "Lucy" },
              { value: "Yiminghe", label: "yiminghe" },
              { value: "disabled", label: "Disabled", disabled: true },
            ]}
            onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
          />
        </Radio>
      </Space>
    </Radio.Group>
  );
};

export default App;


I am experiencing an issue with my dropdown within a radio component in Ant Design. Whenever I attempt to click on the dropdown to expand it, the radio component’s state triggers a re-render. This causes the dropdown to reload, which makes it impossible for me to select any value within the dropdown’s Select component. How to fix it?

Why do you want to add  component inside the ? Do you want to change  value when user select any option from  component?

The problem is not in Ant design, but is more about how React works.
By placing the Select inside a radio, every time you click the radio to open the Select component, the onChange of the Radio.Group is triggered, changing the state of the component and therefore re-render the component. Just remove the Radio wrapper from the Select component and replace it with custom trigger component that looks the same way as the Ant's radio.
